# What is best or Most lightweight/efficient/cheapest RDD action to perform on Huge/large RDD in Apache Spark

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am new to Apache Spark.

Below is the code snippet which demonstrates my sample code.

```
val x = 5
val arrayVal = (1 to 100000)
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(arrayVal, x)//Has Huge RDD of Min 10000 to 100000
var rdd2 = rdd1.map(x => (x, x))
rdd2 = rdd2.cache()
rdd2.count()
val cartesianRDD = rdd2.cartesian(rdd2)
var filteredRDD = cartesianRDD.filter(f => (f._1._1 < f._2._1))
filteredRDD = filteredRDD.repartition(x/2)
rdd2 = rdd2.unpersist(false)
filteredRDD.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)//To avoid re-calculation
filteredRDD.count()
```

As I do count on `RDD` which takes many minutes to count `RDD`. I wants to know what is the best or most efficient/cheapest/lightweight way to trigger `RDD` transformations.

I have also tried `rdd.take(1)` and `rdd.first()` which results the same.

Ultimately my goal is to reduce the time taken by the any of these action. So that total time of execution could be reduced.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your goal here? any kind of action would still do the cartesian which is probably the most time consuming element.

Comment: Yes. I do agree about Cartesian. But after this as it generates 100000 x 100000 records. Count on this rdd holds resources for large time. I just want to reduce the time that Count or take is acquiring to perform task.

Comment: I don't see a reduce here. In any case, in addition to the cartesian, the repartition is also costly. The issue is that any action you perform will have to get all this data.so the calculation would occur.

Comment: one more thing you might want to try is to move rdd2.unpersist only after the filteredRDD.count as the unpersist occurs before you actually use rdd2 in filteredRDD

Comment: Would probably be better to pursue a different approach, but your code sample doesn't provide any context.  I'm guessing you're doing some sort of sequence lag operation? Time series processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rdd.first()` is the cheapest one you can have since it only materializes the first partition.

The cheapest action that will materialize all partitions is `rdd.forEachPartition{_=>_}`.

> Ultimately my goal is to reduce the time taken by the any of these action. So that total time of execution could be reduced.

However, the action you take will not affect the time taken by the previous steps. If you want to decrease total time, you have to optimize other things.

Comment: `foreachPartition` for the exact method name

Comment: Is the Java equivalent `rdd.foreachPartition(iter -> {});`?